# 1970s (?) book where teacher flies in a balloon and crash-lands on mysterious island

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

- **Plot:** The teacher finds an island with very sophisticated civilization. There is a volcano on the island which causes quakes every so often. I also do recall something about families being lettered by the alphabet and making food based on their letter.
- **Format:** 70% chance of paperback | 30% chance of hardcover
- **Language:** English
- **Author:** No clue...
- **Read Date:** Maybe 5-ish years ago...
- **Publication Date:** I'm pretty sure from the early 1970s but I can't be sure, again...

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82456/book-based-on-around-the-world-in-80-days-with-the-main-character-travelling

Comment: A mysterious island, but not [The Mysterious Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Island), right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That would be [The Twenty-One Balloons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twenty-One_Balloons) by William Pene du Bois.  It's a match in every respect.  It was published in 1947 and has had many editions.

The main character is a retired school teacher in the late 1800s.  He had left San Francisco in a balloon, intending to relax. Somehow, he lands on a tropical volcanic island where there's an elaborate society funded by a secret diamond mine.  The families have letter names, Mr. & Mrs. A, B, C, etc., and take turns feeding each other with a cuisine which begins with the letter of their name: American, British, Chinese, etc.  The island has all kinds of odd Victorian gadgetry -- beds on steam-powered hoists, sticks in my mind.

Unfortunately, the island is Krakatoa, it starts erupting and everyone escapes -- just barely -- on a platform held aloft by twenty balloons.

Comment: (Well, not *every* respect!)

Comment: Yeah, I have that one actually ;).  The gadgetry is just from the one house though -- their experimentation lab, almost.  Then the twirly escape balloon system.

Comment: Oh, now I'm remembering everything! Mr. F is the first one he meets! (I think.)

Comment: Wow I forgot this story even existed! Now I want to read it again...

Comment: @Stormblessed **Stop making pointless edits.** A double hyphen is a [common convention](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/hyphenanddash/dash) for representing a dash; revision 9 is totally useless since both forms are correct, and reformatting the sentence from a list of events (with or without Oxford comma) to a double clause divided by a full stop or semicolon is also unnecessary.